# Multiple LoadLibrary for copies of the same DLL

Tags: c, winapi, dll, loadlibrary

I have a DLL which is not thread-safe and must be used by multiple threads. I am not sure how Windows detects loaded DLL-s, whether it is by full file path or by DLL/Module name. If the file path is used, I think it may be possible to copy the DLL in separate files for each thread, e.g. `MyLib1.dll`, `MyLib2.dll`, `MyLib3.dll` and load them with `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Why don't you synchronize the DLL calls with mutex semaphores?

Comment: @sb9 DLL may keep internal state, so mutexes may be insufficient solution.

Comment: Further, mutexes will destroy any prospect for scalability.

Comment: The failure mode that is hard to see are the dependencies of the DLL, they get loaded just once so they may well give you the static state problem back.  And there always is at least one, the C runtime library.  It has static state.  Only truly safe way to do this is to host these DLLs in their own process.

Comment: @HansPassant: This should be an answer. I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

So long as you use the full absolute file name when you call `LoadLibrary`, and so long as these absolute file names are different, then you can load multiple instances.

Personally if it were me I would create the thread, and then copy the DLL to a temporary folder naming  it `<threadID>.dll`. That will guarantee uniqueness of name.

Comment: And what about the case when there are two loaded DLLs that have different filepaths but the same DLL name in export table? Which of them loader should use to resolve imports for some another module that will be loaded later?

Comment: Does this approach create unique memory for each dll?

Comment: @simon that question is imprecise. What do you mean by unique memory

Comment: Never underestimate the power of anti-malware to screw up that scheme :)

Comment: Sorry new to c, I mean for each dll loaded they are self contained?!

Comment: @simon It's not really a matter for C but more a Windows issue. Self contained is still imprecise.

Comment: Would its own heap be precise!?

Comment: @simon that depends. Often not. Common is for all modules in a process to allocate off a single process heap.